# CSS selector help for below structure

Tags: css, selenium, css-selectors, spock, geb

I have to find the anchor "a" nested under table with class as `table.ic-table-creditReportProduct table tr`. I tried but doesn't seem to work. Any ideas where the problem might be or another way to reference it.

**NOTE**: I can't use the id's that have **j_idt** in them as they are auto generated.

[image]

Comment: I can't read that screenshot.

Comment: @fritzfromlondon sory but the SO is reducing the size. so right click and say view it in a new browser or tab

Comment: Cool. It would help if you could copy and paste the code in a jsfiddle.net then we can play with it and see why it doesn't work.

Comment: Simple. Use `.ic-table-creditReportProduct a` as the anchors obviously would be inside a `td`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
table.ic-table-creditReportProduct table tr a
```

should work.

Answer (score 0):

`.ic-table-creditReportProduct a` should do fine. There is no need to specify `table` and `tr` as it is obvious.

Answer (score 0):

Really it depends where else these links will be, and where you need them styling.

The following would style all anchor elements in your web page:

```
a {}
```

This would only style the anchor elements in the table:

```
table.ic-table-creditReportProduct a {}
```

This would only style the anchor elements in the nested table:

```
table.ic-table-creditReportProduct table a {}
```